# Is there any way to restore original fonts supplied with windows?

Tags: windows, fonts, restore

On Windows XP, is there any way to get back original fonts? I uninstalled a bunch of applications now my browser and other applications are missing fonts and displaying the current ones incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Windows XP CD to complete the following:

**Method 1:**

- Make a new folder, something like `C:\Fonts`
- With the XP CD in, type in the following lines, followed by enter after each line (replace D with your CD/DVD drive letter that has the XP CD):

  ```
  expand -r D:\i386\*.tt_ C:\Fonts\*.ttf
  expand -r D:\i386\*.fo_ C:\Fonts\*.fon
  ```
- Select all fonts in `C:\Fonts` and copy them to `C:\Windows\Fonts`
- When asked to overwrite, select "No To All" to ensure new fonts from installed applications remain installed

**Method 2:**

Perform a repair:

- Go to Start -> Run
- Type `sfc /scannow` and press enter, this will replace/fix files that have been altered since the install.

There is a list of fonts packaged with XP **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/winxp.htm)**.